# Looping over list

Tags: r

I've a list in this form:

> s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee","xx")

I want to loop over this list till all the elements are consider. Then I want to check if each element is not equal to "blank". If it's not I want to create a variable which is each element of "s" and concatenation of a constant string, say "_file". Finally stack each of these elements.

The code I created is the following. But it's giving me blank.

```
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee","xx")

t<-if(length(s)>0){
  for(i in s){
    if(length(s)>0){
      i2=i*"_file"
    }
    else{
      i2=''
    }
    i2<-c()
  }
}
```

I tried this as well. But it's running for long.

```
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee","xx")
t<-while(s!=''){
  for(i in s){
    if(length(s)>0){
      i2=i*"_file"
    }
    else{
      i2=''
    }
    i2<-c()
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: @akrun: Thanks for pointing this out. I actually have vector of string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be vectorized using `nzchar`:

```
s <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "", "xx")
paste(s[nzchar(s)], "file", sep="_")
# [1] "aa_file" "bb_file" "cc_file" "dd_file" "ee_file" "xx_file"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've to check if the list is empty or not before pasting "_file". With empty list I'll skip the step.

Comment: @Beta: You mean `s` could be empty? Then simply use `if(length(s))paste(s[nzchar(s)], "file", sep="_")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `sub`

```
sub("^([a-z]+)$", "\\1_file", s)
#[1] "aa_file" "bb_file" "cc_file" "dd_file" "ee_file" ""        "xx_file"
```

#### data

```
s <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "", "xx")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @akrun! But I considered sgibb's answer.

Comment: @Beta Yes, you should consider sgibb's answer as it is more canonical

Answer (score 2):

Just the 'very concise one liner'

```
paste0(Filter(nchar, s), '_file')
```

Comment: Thanks for your elegant answer! But I want to stick with sgibb's one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do. I am sure there are even faster solutions...

```
s <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee","xx")
s[nchar(s)>0]<-paste0(s,"_file")
```

That should do the trick

Comment: `length(s)` returns the length of the vector `s` (i.e. `6`) but not the length of each string in the vector of type `character`. You have to use `nchar` instead (and `nchar(s) > 0` could be replaced by `nzchar(s)`).

Comment: @user3293236: Thanks for your answer. Your answer has same issue as sgibb. So I'm not repeating it. But thanks!